# Outlook script moves attachments to folder but goes newest to oldest

Tags: vba, sharepoint, outlook

I have a script within Outlook that moves an attachment to a folder. The folder is actually SharePoint Online so the file in the attachment is posted to our SharePoint site daily. It works perfectly Monday through Friday when the email is received.

```
 Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Users\xxx\SharePoint\Systems-Information Technolog - SYS 1\xxx"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

However, on Monday when the attachment is received and the rule is activated the attachment for Monday is posted to SharePoint, then the attachment for Sunday is posted and then the attachment for Saturday is posted making the only file available on SharePoint 2 days old.

I realize I can have the report stop arriving on Saturday and Sunday but can the script be modified to only retrieve the most recent attachment and then not run again? The reason this could be important is the attachment in the future could be created multiple times a day so I would need the most recent and no other to be posted.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Attachments do not have dates, mail messages do. Where do you retrieve the message from and how exactly is your code invoked?

Comment: The code is invoked as the email message is received. So during the week everything is okay. But not opening Outlook on Saturday or Sunday causes the results on Monday to be aged.

Comment: Is the script running from a rule? Or from a VBA project that processes the Items.ItemAdd event?

Comment: The script is running from a rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [RecievedTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867228.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the MailItem class which returns a Date indicating the date and time at which the item was received. So, you can check out the received time of each incoming email and save the attachment only if the mail item is the most recent one.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of rule? After the message arrives? Keep in mind that if Outlook is not running, it will not receive new mail motivations (Saturday and Sunday). When Exchange cached store syncs with the server (on Monday), you will see new unread messages in the Inbox, but there will be no new mail motivations and the new mail rules will not fire.

You will need to change your code to run in response to the Items.ItemAdd event on the Inbox folder or run your code manually and process unread messages in the Inbox.